# Moving first value and key to the end on an array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array that looks something like this:

```
'array_1' => [
                'A' => 'A', 'B' => 'B', 'C' => 'C',
             ],
```

I need to shift the first value and key to the end of the array, so it should look like this:

```
'array_1' => [
                'B' => 'B', 'C' => 'C', 'A' => 'A',
             ],
```

I've tried to do it like this:

```
array_push($arr, array_shift($arr));
```

But the result is this:

```
'array_1' => [
                'B' => 'B', 'C' => 'C', '0' => 'A',
             ],
```

The key for value A changed to 0 but i need it ro remain A. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why is the order of the keys so important?

Answer (score 0):

**array_push does not allow you to enter a key**.

Therefore you have to use 
`$arr['key'] = value`

First, do a reset(array). This reset the internal pointer to point at the first element
So that when you use key($arr), it will return the first key.

Then use array_shift() to get the first value in the array

Code:

`reset($arr)
$arr[key($arr)] = array_shift($arr);`

Answer (score 0):

> array_push($arr, array_shift($arr));

This removes the first **VALUE** of $arr, and then adds it to the end of the array as a value, therefore with a numeric key. Since there are no extant numeric keys, it is assigned key 0. Hence your result.

You need to extract the first pair, and push that:

```
reset($arr);
list($k, $v) = each($arr);
array_shift($arr);
$arr[$k] = $v;
```

That said... if you're relying on non-numeric key *order* (or mixed numeric/non-numeric keys), then I fear that your design might be flawed.

A keypair array (a *dictionary*, or sometimes *hash* or *map*) has no key order in most languages and even several representations (most notably, JSON - even if most JSON libraries *usually* maintain insertion order). Assuming it *has* might be setting oneself up for a fall.

Comment: _**Warning** [each()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.each.php) function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.2.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged._ - So perhaps [current()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php) & [key()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php)?